# how to set two fields in mysql update tag

Tags: mysql

```
$query= "UPDATE details  
            SET password 
            AND cpassword = (SELECT newpassword
                                  , cpassword
                               FROM resetpassword 
                              WHERE resetpassword.email = details.email)
          WHERE email = email";
```

Comment: I need to set two fields in details table but its not affecting, if i give one column name its affecting only for that

Comment: Edit your question accordingly.

Comment: See this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5985264/mysql-update-multiple-columns-with-a-select-returning-multiple-rows